# What happens if Spark computation time greater than batch interval

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, bigdata

I am new to spark, What happens if my computation time for a RDD is greater than the batch interval duration, what happens to the RDD on which computation is being done

Comment: At any point of time Dstream consists of single RDD unless we are doing some windowed operation. S what happens to previous RDD if my algo compuation time is greater than batch duration

Comment: You get backlog and hopefully backpressure. If things really get bad, the system will drop messages. Try to optimize your code.